# Phabricator extremely slow

Tags: performance, ubuntu, lamp, phabricator

I am using Phabricator for code reviews, and after tinkering with it, I have gotten it set up more or less exactly as I want.

I just have one problem, that I can't really find a solution to.

Navigating the phabricator app is smooth and has no delays. But when I write a comment (or chose any other action) in the **Leap Into Action** and press **Clowncopterize** it takes forever before it is done. The gears (busy indicator) in the lower right corner keep spinning for up to 60 seconds.

I can't figure out what the cause of this is. I have tried to do a top and I don't see anything severe:

```
top - 11:40:36 up 9 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.10, 0.07
Tasks: 112 total,   1 running, 111 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2044148 total,   526580 used,  1517568 free,    36384 buffers
KiB Swap:  2093052 total,        0 used,  2093052 free,   257344 cached
```

There are no spikes when I press Clowncopterize either. I have made sure DNS is set up correctly. It wasn't to begin with, but is now. Even after a reboot, that didn't fix the performance problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble was that sendmail was incorrectly set up. So it was waiting to time out on sending mails.

Comment: You can avoid such trouble using the Mailgun adapter: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_outbound_email/#adapter-mailgun and https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_inbound_email/#mailgun-setup — They offer a free tier for 10 000 mails.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. But we have since moved on to host our stuff on GitHub, and Phabricator doesn't play well with Pull Requests, so we have started using GitHub for comments and reviews.