# Phabricator performance issues

Tags: google-compute-engine, phabricator

I have a phabricator instance (n1-standard-8, 8 vCPU, 30 GB memory) and the performance is significantly slower than anticipated (~6 second just for document fetch to get a page load).

Initial suspicions pointed to [send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612005/phabricator-extremely-slow) but I thought that setting metamta.mail-adapter to PhabricatorMailImplementationTestAdapter would resolve that. Is there anything else that may be causing this slow down?

Using Apache as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable DarkConsole to find where Phabricator is spending time on page loads.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/darkconsole/